# Binding a dictionary to tabs control with list box inside in wpf

Tags: wpf

I need to create tab control when on each tab there is a list box with related items.
e.g:

[image: example]

What would be the best way to build it dynamically?
TX

Comment: I don't know, Should be some dictionary like Dictionary <string categoryName, List<string> items>

Comment: If you wrote some code, you should post it. In this way people can help you. Otherwise SO is not a "rent-a-coder service".

Comment: Dear rode guy, if you want to help, please do, If you don't please stay out of my post.

Comment: @tal He helps you by telling you, how to write good questions. Better questions have a higher chance of getting an answer than low quality questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding. You can put 3 category for tab headers and add the each list box items as sub category. query the collection for related of tab headers.

EX:

Category :
1. Food
2. Book
3. Car
Sub Category:
1(Food):
   1. Egg 
   2. Meat
   3. Milk
   etc..........